# Longest path in cyclic directed graph with edges that have constrained number of passes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a directed graph with cycles. The most important part about this graph is that every edge has a constraint of how many times it can be passed, and after that it should become "unusable".

How would I go about finding a longest path? Any info or link or comment would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you would need to add a visit counter to each edge while traversing. Have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Not yet, I first wanted some theoretical pointers of how to go about developing an algorithm.

Comment: So there you are (visit counters). I think you should get back to the drawing board. NB: asking for a link to off site resources is mostly off topic here. Please show your research efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), meaning it's very unlikely that there exists a "fast" algorithm (one that will solve every instance in polynomial time); you'll need to either settle for fast heuristics that don't guarantee to find an optimal solution, or use an exponential-time algorithm that will only be able to solve small instances in a reasonable time.

I'll show this by reducing the NP-complete problem [Hamiltonian Path in a Directed Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) (HP) to your problem. Briefly, the idea is: *If* some algorithm exists that solves every instance of your problem "quickly" (meaning in polynomial time), then it could also be used as a subroutine to solve every instance of HP -- and that seems unlikely, since no one knows how to solve HP (or any NP-complete problem) in polynomial time, despite decades of CS research.

In HP, we are given a directed graph G = (V, E), and the task is to determine whether there is a path that visits all |V| vertices exactly once. Given an instance of this problem, we can construct an instance G' of your problem as follows:

- Replace each vertex v with three vertices v_in, v_mid and v_out, change all in-edges to v to be in-edges to v_in, and change all out-edges from v to be out-edges from v_out; call these edges "ebony edges" (they correspond to *edges* in G). Also add edges from v_in to v_mid and from v_mid to v_out; call these edges "velvet edges" (they correspond to a *vertex* in G).
- Assign every edge a pass limit of 1.

There is a path of length 3|V|-1 in this graph if and only if there is a Hamiltonian Path in the original graph G:

**"If" direction:** Suppose G contains a Hamiltonian Path. This corresponds to a path of length 3|V|-1 in the constructed graph that starts and ends with a pair of velvet edges, and alternates between velvet and ebony edges with the pattern VVEVVE...EVV.

**"Only if" direction:** Suppose there exists a path P of length 3|V|-1 in the constructed graph. The pass limit on every edge is 1, so every edge appears at most once in this path. P must have one of the following edge patterns:

1. VVEVVE...EVV
2. VEVVE...EVVE
3. EVVE...EVVEV

In each case, P traverses at least one of the two velvet edges corresponding to each vertex in G, and so corresponds to a Hamiltonian Path in G.